# What type of SID ends with -0?

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, sid

I have been parsing through the logs and found a random sid doing authentications against AD. It is as follows "s-1-5-21-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-0"; It cant be found in domain or forest. I want to know if there is speciality of "-0" at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it's the **domain SID**. Essentially the SID of the domain itself.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/cc228090.aspx

> domain security identifier (domain SID): The SID of the root object of
>   a domain NC. The relative identifier (RID) portion of the domain SID
>   is always zero. Every security principal object in a domain NC has an
>   objectSid attribute equal to the domain SID except for the RID
>   portion.